# How convert scal to frequency when use cwt in matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-analysis, wavelet

I am new in DSP.I have the flowing code

```
t = linspace(0,1,1000);
x = cos(2*pi*60*t);
CWTcoeffs = cwt(x,1:64,'sym8','plot'); 
colormap jet;
```

and my output is:[image]

their have scale in y axis but i represent in frequency 
what is the solution in matlab

Answer (score 2):

I think you should try MATLAB's [**scal2frq**](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/scal2frq.html). You provide the vector of scales, wavelet name and optionally sampling period. This will return vector of pseudo frequencies.

In your case that should be something like:

```
f = scal2frq(1:64, 'sym8', t(1)-t(0));
```